# moving from one fragment to another using viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

So currently my code can move between objects from the same fragment, but I want to move between different fragments that have different layouts.What code do I need to add to viewpager to make it work? Do I need to make use of a FragentManager?  Can anyone guide me on how to go about it? Thanks.

Below if my code:
ScreenSlidePagerActivity.java

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;

    private ViewPager mPager;

    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slide_screen_viewpager);

        //declare viewpager and pageradapter

        mPager = findViewById(R.id.ViewPageSlide);
        pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
            // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
            // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
        else {
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() -1 );
        }
    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
        {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

ScreenSlidePageFragment.java

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.slide_content_page, container, false
        );

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one class i.e.,ScreenSlidePageFragment  that extends fragments. If you want different layouts for that, its better if you create different classes that inflates different layouts. eg: if you want two layouts, create two classes and both classes should inflate different layouts. The changes need to be done are :

```
//inside ScreenSlidePagerAdapter 
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: 
               return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
            case 1:
               return new NewClass();
             //and so on
         }
        
    }
```

You have to create the new Class similar to ScreenSlidePageFragment. The only change is inflate a different layout.

```
public class NewClass extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.new_layout, container, false
    );

    return rootView;
    }
}
```

You can create a new_layout similar to slide_content_page and customize it as you want. You can also increase the no of fragment objects and layout as you wish.

But a new way of doing this things has come. Its better if you extend FragmentStateAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter. This is more easy and efficient. You have to override createFragment in this case instead of getItem. Ignore of you are okay with it.

Hope this is the question you have asked and this helps. Thankyou.

Comment: Keeping a list of fragments in `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` and returning fragments[positon] in `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter.getItem(position)` may be better. Otherwise fragment is a new insance every time showing.